# Code that checks for required text in textboxes upon submit

Tags: php, javascript, validation

how can I check if the user filled some textboxes upon submit? My textboxes have different id and name.

If the user did not fill the required like password the form is not continued.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you wanting to implment the validation client-side? Are you using vanilla JavaScript or can you use jQuery? What does your HTML look like? What have you tried so far? That should get us started.

Comment: you can use `.onsubmit()` method, find all the `<input`s and check their types/values

Comment: what do you mean by "different" ... different than what ? ... are they random ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using JavaScript or within the script itself.

If using javascript, you simply check the form fields against your requirements before allowing the form to submit. However, you may still need to implement this in the script in case ofr some reason they have javascript turned off.

Basically, in the script, you check the values of the form when they submit:

```
if($_GET['field_name']) !== 'the value I expect') {
  // show the form again with errors
}

// continue
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below. Naturally you can tweak the form and id's and such, but the basic principle should work. also shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/j3nSB/2/

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" id="username" value=""/>
    <input type="password" id="password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitButt" value="Go" />
    </form>

    document.getElementById("submitButt").onclick = function () {
        if(document.getElementById("username").value.length == 0 |document.getElementById("password").value.length == 0) {
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't call your submit button `submit` it might cause errors when you'll try to submit the form via JS code.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard it worked fine for me, but i suppose some browsers may choke. updated.

Comment: Cheers, adding a  butt is much better. :-P

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have one form, here is the most simple/generic way I can think of, using plain JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arrRequiredFields = [ "txtPassword", "txtEmail" ];
window.onload = function() {
   document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < arrRequiredFields.length; i++) {
         var field = document.forms[0].elements[arrRequiredFields[i]];
         if (field && field.value.length == 0) {
            alert("Missing required value");
            field.focus();
            return false;
         }
      }
      return true;
   };
};
</script>
```

Just put the names (not ID) of the required elements, put the code in your page and you're all set.

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/kf7pL/

Answer (score 1):

use this:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Its very easy to use, and you can just add a class of 'required' to each required input field.

its as easy as `$('#form').validate();`

It also supports things like integer and date. Highly recommend it to anyone